# Get ApiController instance at run time with .NET 7.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, webapi

I have a Web API application with 2 ApiControllers (that must be kept separated). I use dependency injection and I need to access an instance of an ApiController from the other one. Not being a Service I couldn't get it through constructor or property injection. Is there a way to get the instance of the second ApiController from inside the constructor of the first one in C# ?

Comment: Controllers can be accessed through DI with https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvccoremvccorebuilderextensions.addcontrollersasservices

Answer (score 2):

A minimal example with the default webapi template:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AnotherApiController : ControllerBase
{


    public AnotherApiController (IControllerFactory factory,IHttpContextAccessor accessor) 
    {
        var controllerContext = new ControllerContext()
        {
            HttpContext = accessor.HttpContext,
            ActionDescriptor = new()
            {
                ControllerName = nameof(WeatherForecastController),
                ControllerTypeInfo = new TypeDelegator(typeof(WeatherForecastController))
            }
        };

        var controller = factory.CreateController(controllerContext) as WeatherForecastController;
    }
    .......
}
```

Register HttpContextAccessor in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You made my day. Unfortunately I can give you only on up-vote, but you deserve at least 10-20 :-)